# How to use ExtFilterDefine for png files in perl as one liner?

Tags: apache, perl, filter, httpd.conf

Because of `md5` hash scanning tools like `wpscan`, I want to prevent the script kiddies to detect as much information as possible about my wordpress site. With to following perl snippet, I m trying to add some extra characters to all requested png files. But it does not work and I don't know why. Does somebody can help me out?
My goal is not to change it right inside the files - just for requested output on screen.

`ExtFilterDefine pngfilter mode=output intype=image/png cmd="/usr/bin/perl -pe 'END { unless (-f q{/tmp/md5_filter.tmp}) { print qq(\/*) . time() . qq(\*/) } }'"`

I use the same snippet logic for css and js files. Here it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

It *does* work.

```
$ perl -pe 'END { print qq(/*) . time() . qq(*/) }' derpkin.png >derpkin_.png

$ diff <( hexdump -C derpkin.png ) <( hexdump -C derpkin_.png )
3023,3024c3023,3025
< 0000bce0  00 00 00 00 49 45 4e 44  ae 42 60 82              |....IEND.B`.|
< 0000bcec
---
> 0000bce0  00 00 00 00 49 45 4e 44  ae 42 60 82 2f 2a 31 36  |....IEND.B`./*16|
> 0000bcf0  35 36 33 35 30 37 37 36  2a 2f                    |56350776*/|
> 0000bcfa
```

At least, it works in the sense that it does exactly what you wanted it to do. But does it makes sense to add arbitrary text to the end of a PNG? I'm not familiar enough withe PNG file format to answer that.

Caveat: It will not work on Windows because of CRLF ⇔ LF translation.

Comment: Thanks ikegami. I guess it will work, because wpscan is a linux toll :-). 
Everybody feel free to comment.

Comment: I want to use it for all requested png files like a filter. Not only one certain file like in your snippet above `derpkin.png >derpkin_.png`

Comment: So? the point was to show the program you posted works.

Comment: Could someone give me more tipps? My goal is, that if a png file will be requested, some extra string or timestamp should be added to change the md5 checksum of this file. But the changes should not apply right on the file. That's why I want to use something like ``ExtFilterDefine pngfilter mode=output intype=image/png cmd="/usr/bin/perl -pe 'END { unless (-f q{/tmp/md5_filter.tmp}) { print qq(\/*) . time() . qq(\*/) } }'"``

Comment: Yeah, never said not to

Comment: Please only correct answers to the question. Thanks

Comment: Please only questions that actually identify a problem. Thanks.

Comment: Question was posted in my original post. But thanks for help.

Comment: No, the Question did not identify a problem.